# Error in ./src/index.js Module not found: 'shaka-player-react' in ../src @ ./src/index.js 17:24-53

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use Shaka Player in React to load video content in the page. The stated error is being thrown .
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/index.js Module not found: 'shaka-player-react' in /home/barsha/Documents/study/webassignments/image-gallery/src @ ./src/index.js 17:24-53

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to use a dependency without installing it first?

`npm install shaka-player-react`

Comment: I have installed it . and this is the part of my code- 
.
.
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import ShakaPlayer from "shaka-player-react";

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <App />
    <ShakaPlayer autoPlay src="https://streams.com/example.mpd" />{" "}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

Comment: That all seems good, but to me that error still indicates there was something gone wrong with your installation maybe? Look at your `package.json` and see if you can see `shaka-react-player` there as under dependencies. If you don't, it means you haven't installed it properly. Try running the above install command again and make sure it's there. If it's already there, maybe you deleted your `node_modules` accidentally? Try running just `npm install` in the same directory where `package.json` is. That will make sure all dependencies will be installed and ready in your `node_modules` folder.

Comment: I checked  and "shaka-react-player " exists under dependencies . Help me out ,.. I still cannot figure out the issue, I have tried reinstalling it again inside the folder where package.json exists its throws the same error and i have an assignment to be done in two days.

Comment: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! video-gallery@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the video-gallery@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------this is the current error I'm getting